# Prevent Password Textbox from Being Preloaded

Tags: input, passwords

I have a form with an input type="password" and it gets consistently preloaded with my stored/saved password in Firefox.

It there any way to set the input field to not preload the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the `autocomplete="off"` attribute which is proprietary to IE ans is not XHTML compliant. And checkout the [following blog post](http://verysimple.com/2007/03/07/forcing-firefox-to-obey-autocompleteoff-for-password-fields/) for enforcing it in FireFox which basically uses a timer to clear the value after the page loads.

Comment: This is the best solution - with HTML5 this works in most browsers (Firefox >=3.5, Chrome >=3.0, Safari >=4.0, Opera >=9.5). You could also use a bit of JavaScript to set it to blank on focus.

Comment: Awesome Darin...that worked. I didn't know about the autocomplete attribute.